# Error starting Sinatra under JRuby

Tags: ruby, jruby, sinatra

Ok, giving jruby and sinatra a go, I have no idea whats going on here..

getting this error while trying to perform

rackup app.rb

`gem_original_require': no such file to load -- java (LoadError)`

Nny direction here would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure it's using jruby and not some other ruby on your system?

hat tip to Jörg from the comments

Add this to your app somewhere that executes before the exception is thrown.

`puts RUBY_ENGINE`

Comment: not sure, how can I make sure? I have my path set to bin directory of jruby.

Comment: type `ruby -v` to see the version and type `which ruby` to see where it's at.

Comment: Better yet: examine the constant `RUBY_ENGINE` from within your running app. That way you make sure that you don't have a weird discrepancy between your interpreter and Rack. (For example, if you install Rack under MRI but not under JRuby, and you still have MRI's path somewhere *behind* JRuby's path, then `ruby -v` will print JRuby, but `rackup` will still run under MRI.)

Comment: I think you might want `RUBY_VERSION` instead, as Ruby 1.8.x does not have `RUBY_ENGINE` (and 1.8.6 does not have `RUBY_DESCRIPTION`). Or, better perhaps: `puts \`which ruby\`.strip`